# Objects within asp.net repeater aren't found by my code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, attributes, repeater

So in my asp.net application I have a repeater, but any object inside that repeater can't be found from my code behind.  Here's an example:

**Markup**

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="repeater_id" runat="server"
            DataSourceID="ExampleSource">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table id="table_id">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Example</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="MyLabel" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

And in my Page Load I'm trying to add an attribute like this:

**C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyLabel.Attributes.Add("Example","Example");
        }
```

However, in my aspx.cs page, "MyLabel" is highlighted as a build error, with a description "The name 'MyLabel' does not exist in the current context."  Anbody know what that could be?  **If MyLabel is before or after the repeater, it works just fine.**

Anybody know what my problem is?  Please explain as clearly as possible, I'm new to coding.

Edit: Mistyped my coding within the question.  Fixed now.

Comment: consult with this site for example on how to format and setup ItemTemplate http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through `repeater_id.Items` and find the label like below

```
foreach (RepeaterItem ri in repeater_id.Items)
{
    Label MyLabel = (Label)ri.FindControl("MyLabel");
    MyLabel.Attributes.Add("Example","Example");
}
```